# Why do we care about non-equal but isomorphic objects in a category?

Tags: category-theory, philosophy

Note: this is more of a philosophical question.

Said differently, what if we were to ask Categories to be extensional in the sense that if two objects are isomorphic then they are equal?

Is there any example where we do *not* want this?

And notice that this of course shouldn't make every isomorphism an identity. We still have different automorphisms.

At least intuitively I find this to follow the structuralist view of what an object is.

Comment: Can you clarify the sense of "equal" that is not "identity", especially since you allow non-trivial automorphisms?

Comment: @paulgarrett ah, sorry if something was not clear. It isn't in my mind so I might be saying confusing stuff.

Comment: Well, right, I think it's intrinsically impossible, is why it's intrinsically confusing! :)  Perhaps under certain conditions (on automorphisms?) it is possible... And there is the notion of "skeleton" of a category (as in choosing $\mathbb C^n$ for an $n$-dimensional complex vectorspace). But at least from my amateur-category-theorist viewpoint, it is not generally possible to do what you want. More expert people will surely give more precision.

Comment: @paulgarrett [continuation...] As I understand it, for a category we can give two different objects and arrows in between them that satisfy the definition of isomorphism. A category is basically a preorder, so we are missing the quotient that gives an associated partial order to get to what I was talking about.

Comment: @paulgarrett I'll wait for someone to chime in then. And thanks for the comment. :D

Comment: Every category has a *skeleton* and is even equivalent with it. So, for most purposes we can work only with skeletal categories. About the question in the title: we care non-skeletonal categories because they arise naturally in most application area.

Comment: If we force isomorphic objects to become equal, then I think we are effectively choosing isomorphisms between those objects. There is often no canonical choice of such an isomorphism (for example between two $n$-dimensional vector spaces), so we would be imposing structure that is not present in the original category.